# Call to set Bottomsheet STATE_EXPANDED is not waiting for layout resize after first calling hideSoftInputFromWindow

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, bottom-sheet

In an activity that takes user input, I have a "+" toolbar button that does two things: hide the softkeyboard, then set the state of the bottomsheet to expanded. Sounds simple right? I hope for someone it is.

The problem is that the bottomsheet displays on top of the softkeyboard, even though the keyboard has since closed. It's just sitting in the middle of the screen. If I touch it slightly without closing it, then it jumps down to the bottom, as if it knows it's meant to be there.

Does anyone know how to make this work correctly?

I don't want to disable resizing in the manifest as then the user can't scroll through input fields when the keyboard is open. Is there some way to make the second action wait for the resize to complete?

Comment: Can you show your `xml` code and properties you set in `AndroidManifest` to that `activity`?

Comment: It's very basic. I have set the name, label, theme, parentActivityName, and meta-data for the parent activity. The theme is AppThem.NoActionBar. That's it.

Comment: @Michael did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No I didn't find a way to do it. I decided it wasn't so bad to just not hide the keyboard, and at least that way it behaves in a predictable manner. Also, the sheet is then closer to where the user last touched so it has that benefit.